# Is it important to understand Linear algebra geometrically?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am currently self studying linear algebra, using Axler's text. And I always find myself trying to picture every theorem and proposition by considering some low dimensional cases, in order to understand why the theorems make sense. As I get to the chapter for eigenvalues and eigenvectors, things are getting a bit abstract.

Specifically, he proved that every linear operator over an odd dimensional real vector space must have an eigenvalue by using induction, he considered the case where $U$ is a $2$ dimensional invariant subspace of $V$, set $W$ such that $U\oplus W=V$. Then consider the projection of $T\vec w$ onto $W$ along $U$ as an operator in $L(W)$, which must have an eigenvalue $\lambda$ by induction hypothesis. In the end, he showed that $T-\lambda I$ is not injective, thus $\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue of $T$.

I understand everything he's written, but failed to grasp the bigger picture as I can only imagine vector space up to $3$ dimensions (in which case $W$ is only one dimensional). The construction is remarkable for me, as two different linear operators have the same eigenvalue, which I have no idea what the picture would look like (e.g. where does the eigenvector lie on) in higher dimensional spaces.

> > So my question: Is understanding linear algebra through picture important? In some sense, I feel like it helps me understand more why some theorems would be true, but the proofs/constructions **do not** rely on picture at all as they mostly involve algebraic manipulations.

Comment: Yes, because linear algebra *is* geometric, in some sense. In fact, in modern mathematics, one can construct affine and projective geometries (etc.) from linear algebra.

Comment: In my personal opinion geometric interpretation of linear algebra concepts and results is not useful at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of scientific and mathematical knowledge proceeds from what we directly understand as self-evident to what must logically follow from that. So it is important to understand that that fact about the nature of knowledge applies to any subfield of mathematics.

Easily perceived examples in lower dimensions are an important starting point in grasping the truth of propositions applied by logic to higher dimensions.

Eigenvectors and eigenvalues depend fundamentally upon the concepts of $\textbf{direction}$ and $\textbf{length}$ which we understand by direct perception in lower dimensions.

We can construct lower dimensional examples of linear transformations and directly understand why they leave the directions of certain vectors unchanged, changing perhaps only their length. This is important to understanding the possibility, confirmed by reason, that the same phenomenon can exist in higher dimensions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think my main doubt is that sometimes the propositions could become too complicated that considering low dimensional cases doesn't really help in getting the intuition. While through algebraic construction, the logic is clearer and more understandable, but it is harder to get the big picture of why the method would work. Anyway I will keep in mind that I should always consider low dimensional cases to try to at least get a brief picture.

Comment: Your concern about complications in higher dimensions haunts all mathematician. Michael Atiyah says: "Algebra is the offer made by the devil to the mathematician. The devil says: I will give you this powerful machine, it will answer any question you like. All you need to do is give me your soul: give up geometry and you will have this marvelous machine."